# NullPointerException in main

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception, char

Yes, I know this has been brought up alot.
Yes, I know the answer will probably be something stupid and simple that I missed.

```
public char [] [] board;

 public Gameboard(boolean setup){

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        board[j][i] = '-';
      }
    }
```

I am initializing a blank game board, (8x8).
The dash marks represent blank spaces, and I am initializing the whole board, and plan to add pieces later.

This is the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Gameboard.<init>(Gameboard.java:9)
    at Student_Runner_Gameboard.main(Student_Runner_Gameboard.java:4)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: ..`board` is `null` it is not initialized, you see?

Comment: `board[j]` is `null`. Initialize it with an array. And if you switch `i` and `j` around, you will make your life easier

Comment: *I am initializing a blank game board* no you're not ==> `board=new char[7][7]`